# Is a tour of a US Embassy possible?

Tags: usa, uk, london, us-citizens, embassies

Just as [seeing the inside of tech companies](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38844/4868) would be interesting, I think it could be interesting to see the inside of embassies too. Let's say I was going to be in London for a week and wanted to see the inside of the US embassy in London.

Looking at the [list of services US embassies offer](http://travel.state.gov/content/studentsabroad/en/embassies/their-role.html), I guess I could do something like...  print out the form to [re-issue US savings bonds](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/forms/sav4000.pdf) and try to have them notarize it, but if I didn't actually have US savings bonds that needed to be re-issued it seems like that would be a bit scammish. It also seems like the US embassy might wonder why I couldn't just wait a week and do it when I got back to the states.

Comment: Do you mean the citizen services area, or the offices part where the diplomatic staff work? The former is likely much easier than the latter.

Comment: Either would be interesting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer: No, not for ordinary mortals.  In the 1990's they hosted a wonderful 4th of July party, but 9/11 took care of that in short order.

It is hard enough to get in when you want to discuss something...

> As we have very limited counter space and no private area where we
>   could discuss your case I would discourage you from coming in to the
>   Embassy.  We only ask people to come into the Embassy if there is
>   mandatory requirement that they be seen in person.

Source: email from the [Federal Benefits Unit](http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/acs/fbu/)

The [Internal Revenue Service](http://london.usembassy.gov/irs/) used to operate a walk-in service, which is being curtailed.

If you have a newborn baby who has a claim on US citizenship, you can still get in.  It's a large room with some nursery fixtures like a play box.  There's about a dozen windows where you get called up according to your number.  The ambience is strollers everywhere with screaming babies in various states of distress.  Mothers getting angry about the waiting times...  The odd diaper change...  Normally there's a few people waiting to speak to Social Security or the Veteran's Administration.  A bottled water vending machine...  A confectionery vending machine...  A literature stand with every kind of brochure known to mankind about paying your taxes on time...   Not much of touring material.

There's an altogether separate facility for people wanting to join the Navy, etc. People who want to speak to a Navy (etc) Recruiter or enlist will get sent there.  Asylum seekers will get **swarmed** **upon** by the UK police and hauled away to Yarl's Wood; you can't get in that way.

You'll observe from Grosvenor Square that there's a forward control point outside to screen visitors.  You need to be on their list of people with appointments for that day.  Americans have one queue, non Americans have their own queue.

[image]

[image]

Source: [US Embassy](http://www.slideshare.net/USAinUK/presentations)

If they find a mobile or camera, you'll be sent back to a pharmacy near Oxford Street to check it in, and then when you return you can wait in the queue all over again.  You can't even access the forward control point if you have a mobile on your person.

I don't know the procedure for your specific example about US Savings Bonds.  My *guess* is that they would look in your passport and see you arrived just a few days earlier and probably that you acquired the bonds stateside and conclude that it's too dodgy and then turn you over to the British police who would 'ask' you to leave the Grosvenor Square vicinity.  But that's strictly a *guess*.

**Opinion divides about what a 'tour' is**.  So far, this answer has addressed just getting in to the waiting room and consular area.  The embassy itself is in an altogether different part of the building which you can't even see from the consular area.  It even has its own entrance (which can't be seen from the street).

So if 'tour' means entering the Embassy from Blackburne's Mews and then seeing the reception hall, the gallery, the ball room, the dining room, the state room, the ambassador's office and such. Plus any back office parts like the kitchen, the ceremonial unit barracks, or whatever, then the answer becomes even more trenchant.

My advice: forget it.

This answer is for [ordinary mortals only](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/ordinary%20mortals).  Of course foreign dignitaries and congressional aides can get in and see what it looks like.  Note that local residents in and around Grosvenor Square *bitterly* and *stridently* want the US Embassy gone because the security is a blight on the neighbourhood.  So perhaps this answer will change when and if the Embassy is re-sited.

Comment: Wow, I guess a lot of babies pop out in London.  When we registered our daughter's birth at the US Embassy in another country, we sat in a tiny waiting room along with everyone else, no kids stuff, just benches and a water cooler.

Comment: @Tom, does it mean you missed out on the screaming?

Comment: Yep, no other babies that day, just a teenager having his birth registered.

Comment: @GayotFow Great answer and pic, however the pic has a watermark.. any chance you could find a public domain picture?

Comment: @Tom, check out this thread  http://talk.uk-yankee.com/index.php?topic=4481.0

Comment: @CGCampbell, I think it qualifies as fair use, but I can have a look to see what's out there.

Comment: I'm a bit hypersensitive since I was accused of picture plagiarism in another answer in this same exchange.

Comment: That's one longggg thread.  I found the process to be a breeze, downloaded and filled out forms, went in for the appointment, came out 30 minutes later with our Certificate, got the passport two weeks later. Likewise easy to get her other passport.  Now at the ripe old age of two and a half she is a veteran traveler, with trips to Europe and southern Africa under her belt and stamped in her two passports.

Comment: @Tom, just remember to take 'progressive photos' and to prep your child for an interview about where the photos were taken, etc I have been through the drill three times and at the last one my son couldn't remember the name of our cat!!!

Comment: Interview for what?

Comment: @Tom, you will need to renew her passport when she's five. If you are still abroad, your child will get interviewed.  Mostly about the pictures plus maybe a wild card like "Where's Mommy?"  They showed one of mine a photo of his grandmother and he professed not to know who it was.  VERY TENSE MOMENT

Comment: In my experience it is possible to enter US embassies.  They provide citizen services after all.  It is like the DMV.  If you want to go to the DMV to watch people waiting in line, no one is stopping you.

Comment: @gayot - that shan't be an issue, lots of photos with and without both parents.

Comment: @emory, put it in an answer. People may not read all the comments

Comment: About the "ordinary mortals" bit: is it maybe possible to get to see it if you talk to your congressman's office, or is that not something they can/will help with?

Comment: @cpast, put it in an answer. People may not read all the comments.

Comment: @GayotFow I was wondering if you knew (following up on "congressional aides"); I have no idea if it'd work.

Comment: @cpast, I don't know, but I strongly suspect they will slag ordinary mortals off.  Donald Trump could do it, but not Kim Kardashian. But that's a guess. Best to put it in an answer.

Comment: Wanting to see the inside of the US embassy in London is definitely an excellent reason to have a child.

Answer (score 10):

US embassies are probably among the most difficult to access but since your question suggests you might be interested in other embassies too, note that there are many options to visit one.

For example, in London, some embassies participate in the annual [“Open House” event](http://www.openhouselondon.org.uk/) (e.g. [Czech Republic](http://events.londonopenhouse.org/building/19230), [Belgium](http://events.londonopenhouse.org/building/18794)), host occasional cultural events ([North Korea](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/nov/04/inside-north-korea-london-embassy)!) or have a [public library](http://www.uk.emb-japan.go.jp/en/embassy/index.html) on their premises.

In Washington, EU embassies even host their own “open house” event and you can visit [the EU delegation and many EU countries' embassies on the same day](http://www.euopenhouse.org/) (since embassies are generally pretty boring, they also organize a lunch, activities for kids, etc. at this occasion).

Other embassies located in especially significant buildings organize regular tours for tourists, e.g. the [Palazzo Farnese](http://www.ambafrance-it.org/Visiter-le-Palais-Farnese-414) in Rome (embassy of France) or the [Hôtel de Beauharnais](http://www.allemagne.diplo.de/Vertretung/frankreich/fr/01-Botschaft/03-residenz/04-visites-seite.html) in Paris (official residence of the ambassador of Germany).

And of course, having a legitimate purpose (collecting a passport, voting, etc.) will give you a glimpse into your own country's embassy/consulate (although, in my experience, you generally don't see much and they often have separate facilities in the basement or a building adjacent to the embassy to receive the public).

Comment: I don't think voting will help much in this case, since US elections are run by the states.  When I lived in Europe, I had to write to Pennsylvania to get an absentee ballot, because that was the last state I had been registered in before I moved abroad.

Comment: @phoog I don't know whether the OP is a US citizen, I had other embassies in mind…

Comment: I was speaking of the US embassy because the OP is asking specifically about it.  That is also why I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that the OP is a US citizen.  If not, then voting will *certainly* not be an option to gain access, nor will any passport-related business.

Comment: @phoog True but see the first sentence in my answer. Relevant or not, it's not about US embassies.

Comment: Oops.  my problem is that I must have scanned your answer rather hastily, after which I clearly forgot that I had done so.

Comment: I hear that the Ecuador embassy even has a dormitory now!

Answer (score 3):

Aside from security (mentioned by https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44926/2387) and time (you can only go during citizen service hours), visiting a US embassy is not difficult.

You don't need to have a reason to visit the embassy and if you think you do then you can always renew your passport, request extension pages, or request they notarize some paper.  Once inside you don't have to do any of these things.  Since these services cost money, you can simply tell them that you don't have the money and they'll take your word for it and not provide the service.

That being said - why would you visit the embassy.  It is like a DMV for expats.  Do you visit the DMV in your hometown for fun?  When visiting other US states, do you tour their DMV facilities?

Comment: W.r.t. to the DMV analogy... just walking in and out of the lobby could be interesting. Sure, it may not hold your interest for very long but then whomever said you had to be in the lobby for very long? You could just walk in, walk around, and walk out and add it to the list of buildings you've seen the inside of. To each their own..

Comment: @neubert indeed.  Almost anything can be interesting for a short enough period of time.  Speaking of DMV offices, you might find it interesting that I was married in the same room where I took my first driving test.  The state DMV moved out of that building, and the city clerk moved into it, sometime between the two events.  I doubt that fact will hold your interest for very long, however.

Comment: @neubert if you want to visit the US embassy then go for it.  You can use their restroom or drink water from their drinking faucet.  You paid for it with your tax dollars.

Comment: @emroy - Per Gayot Flow, it's not quite that simple. Quoting his post, "there's a forward control point outside to screen visitors. You need to be on their list of people with appointments for that day". So how do you propose someone get an appointment to use their restroom? Just because it was paid for by tax dollars doesn't mean it's freely accessible by the public. My tax dollars also paid for stealth fighters but that, in and of itself, doesn't mean I'm able to sit in the cockpit of a stealth fighter.

Comment: @neubert go to https://evisaforms.state.gov/acs/make_default.asp?pc=LND click "Request notarial and other services not listed above." and make the appointment.  I think the restroom and water fountain are the only no-fee services.