# Facebook datacenter location

Tags: usa, california, geek-travel, nevada, silicon-valley

Me and my father are headed to LA, Las Vegas and Silicon Valley 3-8 january, 2015 to attend CES in Las Vegas.
We're travelling to Silicon Valley to explore it and see if we can see the big company buildings.

Do any of you know the location of the Facebook datacenter there?
Is it possible to get there to see it from the outside?
(Maybe possibly a short visit to the inside?)

Comment: See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/computer-geek-tourist-attractions-in-the-san-francisco-bay-area-silicon-valley) and [this one mentioning facebook](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38844/visiting-software-development-companies-in-la-area-silicon-valley) for references.

Answer (score 10):

Facebook does not have a datacenter anywhere in CA. Their datacenter is in Oregon and another one elsewhere in USA (but I know for a fact that there is none in CA).
They also have one in Sweden.
In Silicon Valley they have servers but those are colocated at datacenters run by different companies.

Visiting a datacenter from outside is never a problem but inside a datacenter access is strictly monitored and not everyone can go there.
To be honest there is nothing to see inside, it's just boxes and cables and that's all.

Comment: Ahh, I see - I'll look for some other cool places to visit