# What technologies are available in San Francisco in 2020 that aren't widely available elsewhere?

Tags: san-francisco

What technologies (consumer or otherwise) should a tech-interested tourist seek out when visiting the forefront of technology, San Francisco?

Some ideas:

- robot-made coffee
- home automation, e.g. guesture to open blinds
- drone transport?
- autonomous uber/lyft?

Please give links and specific examples/places where possible!

Comment: Can you name some from recent years which were not for sale world wide within a very short time?

Comment: Good question. I think self driving cars are common in the US? (not common or even allowed where I am). I haven't seen gestures used around the home (seen on video of course, but not in person) - I think that's more common in SF? Electric bike variants have strict wattage limits where I am. It will be years until flying taxies are allowed where I am (I believe dubai is trialing them, not sure about SF)

Comment: @Willeke it is only my guess that some interesting technologies exist there that are worth checking out. Not just because SF is known for tech, but also because of the the more progressive regulations (at least, more progressive than where I am - at least 2 -3 years ahead of where I am I guess).

Comment: @user5783745 self-driving cars are not *common* in the US. They exist - as test projects for tech companies, but that's it.

Comment: I personally think you will likely get as good a list (or as poor a one) when you name a random other main city. But that is because I do not think it still takes months or years for tech to get released across the world, if not in all locations.

Comment: The biggest chain of robot-made coffee places [just closed down](https://abc7news.com/5830767/) the other day, though they say they're going to do airports now. The [robot burger joint](http://creator.rest/) is still in business though.

Comment: I'd challenge the "more progressive regulations" bit too. The city has an extremely strong regulatory streak that reacts immediately with legal threats and new rules to things like scooter rental (they were banned for months until a capped permit program was put in place) and sidewalk delivery robots (basically banned except for a limited test that allows not more than 9 in the whole city, with restrictions).

Comment: This is a good point. The SF government does not like being at the forefront of tech and is doing all they can to make the lives of tech companies and workers miserable. But that's a discussion for another site...

Comment: The claim "the forefront of technology, San Francisco" is quite debatable, as you will realize soon after landing SFO airport, which has no automated security gate unlike some other airports that use automated facial recognition technology (e.g , HKG). You'll then take the car to San Francisco and realize the road safety is much inferior to the autobahn in Germany. Or maybe you'll take the Caltrain/Bart, whose technology is archaic compared to recently built trains in China. Etc.

Comment: For self-driving cars, Las Vegas and probably Phoenix are better choices.  Lyft has been testing them in Las Vegas for probably the past year or so and I've gotten one on accident by requesting a normal Lyft ride (I think your rating needs to be above a certain threshold to get one, though, and you can't take as many passengers because the front seats are occupied by employees monitoring the ride).  Waymo does testing in Phoenix with members of the public, but I'm not sure what's it takes to get involved with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Willeke notes, successful things tend to spread quickly, so there isn't a lot of consumer technology that doesn't make it to other cities soon enough. That said, here are some few ideas that broadly approach the topic:

**E-bike share** - Bike share systems, even those with electric options, are hardly unique to San Francisco, but the city now has two operators with some of the best shared e-bikes out there (though the [Smide](https://www.smide.ch/index_en.html) system in Switzerland looks glorious): [Bay Wheels](https://www.lyft.com/bikes/bay-wheels) (Lyft; many of the bikes in this system are currently not electric) and [JUMP](https://www.jump.com/) (Uber). Download the app, find a bike, and go for a ride.  The Bay Wheels app has a map that marks bike-friendly streets (your definition of friendly may vary from the city's) with green lines and dots.

[**Scoot**](https://scoot.co/san-francisco/) - Electric mopeds available for rent by the minute (also one of the kick scooter rental companies; they're owned by Bird). Download the app, learn to ride, cruise around town, and park on the street within the service area or in one of their garages. A US driver's license is required, but you don't need a motorcycle license.

[**Creator burgers**](http://creator.rest/) - Burger-making robot restaurant

**Autonomous vehicles** - [Cruise](https://www.getcruise.com/) tests autonomous vehicles in the city and you can sometimes see them around, but there's no public ride-hail service with autonomous vehicles.

**VR** - There have been a few VR arcades where you can try out virtual reality gear, though the equipment and these businesses are not in any way unique to San Francisco. Several have closed down, but there are [a few in operation](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Vr%20Arcade&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA).

[**Amazon Go**](https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=16008589011) - They started these in Seattle and are in several US cities now, but checkout-free convenience stores. Download the app (or take advantage of the new city law that requires them to offer a cash option), login to your Amazon account, scan in at the entrance gates, grab what you want off the shelf, and walk out. Sensors track your actions, and you'll get a notification with your receipt within a few minutes.

Museums - The [Tech Museum](https://www.thetech.org/) is an interactive technology museum. It's located in San Jose, so it will take a bit of a journey from San Francisco. You could combine that trip with a visit to the [Computer History Museum](https://computerhistory.org/) and [other tech-related things to see in Silicon Valley](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/computer-geek-tourist-attractions-in-the-san-francisco-bay-area-silicon-valley/6010). [NASA Ames Research Center](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/about/aboutames-faqs.html) isn't usually open to the public, but has a small gift shop with some exhibits. The [Exploratorium](https://www.exploratorium.edu/) is an interactive science museum in San Francisco; Thursday evenings are adults-only nights, with special programming and alcohol available; consider the additional ticket (get them before they're gone) for the [Tactile Dome](https://www.exploratorium.edu/visit/tactile-dome), a unique experience built in the 1970s.

[**b3ta**](https://b8ta.com/) - A chain store that sells a variety of technology and gadgets. Not unique to SF, and the items are otherwise sold online all over the world, but might be something you'd be interested in seeing.

**Tours** - Absolutely in no way unique to SF, but there are Segway tour companies. A better option is to rent some Segways yourself from [this outfit](https://goldengateparksegwayrentals.com/) and go explore the park on your own; try not to hurt yourself if you go off-road. [GoCar](https://www.gocartours.com/locations/san-francisco/) rents out these awkward little GPS-guided three-wheeled tour vehicles.

[**Bay Model**](https://www.spn.usace.army.mil/Missions/Recreation/Bay-Model-Visitor-Center/) - A different kind of technology, this is a working hydraulic model of the entire San Francisco Bay-Delta system, originally built in the 50s to study the effects of proposed dams. It's in Sausalito north of the city (across the Golden Gate bridge); see [directions](https://www.spn.usace.army.mil/Missions/Recreation/Bay-Model-Visitor-Center/Directions/).

[**Cable cars**](https://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/muni/cable-cars) - The technology is nearly 200 years old, but you won't find ones like these anywhere else in the world anymore. Get the MuniMobile app or a Clipper card to save time waiting for tickets. The [Cable Car Museum](http://www.cablecarmuseum.org/)/barn/powerhouse is worth a visit too.

The robot-made coffee chain [just closed](https://abc7news.com/5830767/); there's no home automation options you can't get anywhere else; no drone delivery services; and no autonomous taxi service open to the public.

Comment: I would say that about a third or even half the things you mention are also in Lisbon and as I have not studied it in details, the percentage may even be higher. And that is just one random city, I think that the things missing in Lisbon may well be found in many other cities.

Comment: @Willeke Sure, but I thought a list of things a "tech-interested tourist" might want to see would at least be more useful than rejecting the premise of the question entirely. And I pointed out most of the things that are available elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the (awesome) answer. I have broadened the question to expand beyond consumer tech to anything a tourist might be interested in. Also, in a comment on the question, did you mention sidewalk delivery robots!?

Comment: @user5783745 Thanks! There essentially are no sidewalk delivery robots in SF besides an [extremely limited test program](https://www.sfpublicworks.org/services/permits/autonomous-delivery-devices) (only 9 allowed for the whole city, time limited, in specific areas only, human nearby, etc...). There have been a few other experiments, including [Kiwibot in Berkeley](https://www.berkeleyside.com/2019/12/02/kiwibot-berkeleys-pioneering-robot-delivery-startup-is-ending-service), a test by Doordash, and Starship Technologies on several east coast college campuses.

Comment: I've seen some sidewalk delivery robot tests in downtown Palo Alto, although I'm not sure what the current status of them is.  Outside of the Bay Area, the Vdara hotel in Las Vegas also has them for room service delivery.

Comment: Waymo does some self-driving car tests around Palo Alto/Mountain View (employees use them to get around), but I'm not sure how well marked they are, and they're not for public use.  The Cruise garage is somewhere in SoMa (maybe around 11th/Howard), so it's quite easy to see their cars in that general area, especially later at night when there's less traffic.